# Using PrepareStatement to get data with configurable table name

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get some data from Oracle 11.2 using java and jdbc driver.

My goal is to get data from database using CallableStatement, but with no luck - I'm not able to put table name as parameter. I would like to have configurable table name in query. However, it would be good to keep it sanitized.

Here is an example..

```
public void getData() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = Config.getSQLConnection();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM ?";
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, Config.DATATABLE_NAME);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        System.out.println("ID:" + rs.getString("ID"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
    }
}
```

Is this the way it should work? Or am I missing something, or misused it?

Comment: Edited to use PreparedStatement instead of CallableStatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CallableStatement` is used to make call to stored procedures.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html):

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures

Use a `PreparedStament` instead for a normal select.

As an additional note don't pass the name of the table as parameter.
Create the query using concatenation.

Instead of

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM ?";
```

use

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Config.DATATABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: So, I have to use contatenation, even when I leave configuration to admin users? Would it be sanitized this way?

Comment: You have to check how the sql will be created. It is not sanitized. But the problem is that the table name is not a parameter. It is part of the query. The parameters can be represented with the question mark, not the table names

Answer (score 0):

You should use PreparedStatement instead of CallableStatement.
CallableStatement is an interface which is used to call stored procedures.